# Lubuntu 18.04: "Symbol lookup error:undefined symbol: SSL_library_init"

Tags: lubuntu, 18.04, openssl

I am trying to run a script that initializes a firebase connection and then does a test write/read to a new collection. Upon running the script on Node.js 8.10.0 I get this error:

`node: symbol lookup error: /home/owner/PhpstormProjects/folder_name/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node: undefined symbol: SSL_library_init`

Here is the code:

```
const firebase_admin = require("firebase-admin");
const firebase_service_account = require("../project_name-firebase-admin-xyz");

firebase_admin.initializeApp({
        credential: firebase_admin.credential.cert(firebase_service_account)
    });

const firestore = firebase_admin.firestore();

console.log("line 11");

let docRef = firestore.collection("test").doc("alovelace");

let setAda = docRef.set({ first : "Ada" });

console.log("line 17");
```

The output:

```
owner@G700:~/PhpstormProjects/project_folder$ node ./gitignore/scratch_area/firebase_1a_minimal.js
line 11
line 17
node: symbol lookup error: /home/owner/PhpstormProjects/project_folder/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node: undefined symbol: SSL_library_init
```

I've tried removing `let setAda = docRef.set({ first : "Ada" });` . This prevented the error message.

It seems to be an issue with setting a new record, either on the Firestore side, or with SSL/gRPC/Node.js/Lubuntu. I believe my machine is the most likely issue. Here is the relevant software:

- Node.js 8.10.04
- Lubuntu 18.04

I appreciate any feedback, thanks.

Comment: SSL_library_init is an old OpenSSL symbol. OpenSSL 1.0.2 has it, but the latest OpenSSL 1.1.0 does not (the two versions are not fully source compatible). The default OpenSSL version available in 18.04 is 1.1.0. It sounds like something in your stack has a dependency on the old OpenSSL version.

Comment: Thanks, I asked about how to roll back elsewhere and did so with 1.0.2. But even after running the script again the same issue occurs. Further, I ran this command to see if the correct files installed and they did appear to:

`owner@G700:~/PhpstormProjects/refund_reducer$ apt policy libssl1.0.0
libssl1.0.0:
  Installed: 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5
  Candidate: 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5 500
        500 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: You likely have both 1.0.2 and 1.1.0 installed on your system (I just checked and both are installed on my 18.04 installation)

Comment: In this case would removing version 1.1.0 solve anything if 1) taken out of path  2) uninstalled completely?

Comment: Uninstalling completely would probably break a lot of stuff so I would advise against that. I guess you need to figure out why its trying to load the wrong version...but I can't help there :-(